# Extract string from a dataframe comparing to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract strings from a DF in pandas dataframe and the source strings are in a list from which I have to match. I tried using a `df.str.extract(list1)` but i got an error of unhashable types i guess i the way I compare the list to the DF is not correct

> From

```
Col 1   Col 2
1       The date
2       Three has come
3       Mail Sent
4       Done Deal
```

> To

```
Col 1   Col 2           Col 3 
1       The date        NaN
2       Three has come  Three has
3       Mail Sent        Mail
4       Done Deal        Done
```

My list is like below

```
List1 = ['Three has' , 'Mail' , 'Done' , 'Game' , 'Time has come']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `join` all values in `List` by `|` what means `or` in `regex`:

```
List1 = ['Three has' , 'Mail' , 'Done' , 'Game' , 'Time has come']
df['Col 3'] = df['Col 2'].str.extract("(" + "|".join(List1) +")", expand=False)
print (df)
   Col 1           Col 2      Col 3
0      1        The date        NaN
1      2  Three has come  Three has
2      3       Mail Sent       Mail
3      4       Done Deal       Done
```

Another solution:

```
List1 = ['Three has' , 'Mail' , 'Done' , 'Game' , 'Time has come']

df['Col 3'] = df['Col 2'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([L for L in List1 if L in x]))
df['Col 3'] = df['Col 3'].mask(df['Col 3'] == '')
print (df)
   Col 1           Col 2      Col 3
0      1        The date        NaN
1      2  Three has come  Three has
2      3       Mail Sent       Mail
3      4       Done Deal       Done
```

Comment: Tried this but got the error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1`

Comment: Problem is with sample or with real data?

Comment: Problem is with the real data. Having nos in some cells or special chars like - or _ will make a difference ?

Comment: Yes, there has to be problem. Because it seems some characters are read as regex. Can you extract all special chars?

Comment: Since they list actually contains server names I will not be removing the special chars

Comment: Yes, I know. But you need escape by `\` this special chars for correct working.