# Using lambda IF condition on columns in Pandas to extract and replace strings from a data frame comparing to a list

Tags: pandas, string, list, lambda, replace

An example df

```
data = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'location':['Havana,Cuba', 'Santiago de Cuba' , 'La Habana', 'Cuba', 'Havana, Cuba', 'Santiago, Chile', 'Chile']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I use the following to split the string in **location** column.

```
# Splits string into two new columns
df[['location_1', 'location_2']] = df['location'].str.split('[,|.]', 1, expand=True)
```

I need to further process by checking the value of **LOCATION_1** against a list. If it meets one of the the **STRING** values from the list I need to replace the value of **LOCATION_2** with the match list value and replace the **LOCATION_1** value with "".

The example below ([based on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954822/extract-string-from-a-dataframe-comparing-to-a-list)) is a start but needs to be conditional on a match with the list as it overwrites existing data in **LOCATION_2**. Another helpful solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443082/using-lambda-if-condition-on-different-columns-in-pandas-dataframe) but does not use a List.

```
sample_list=['Cuba','Chile']
df['location_2'] = df['location_1'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([L for L in sample_list if L in x]))
df['location_2'] = df['location_2'].mask(df['location_2'] == '')
print(df)
```

Finally, I am not trying to only extract "Cuba" and "Chile" but I also need to modify a string such as "Santiago de Cuba" to result in "Santiago de" in **LOCATION_1** and "Cuba" in **Location_2**.

Final table should look something like this.

```
id          location   location_1 location_2
0   1       Havana,Cuba       Havana       Cuba
1   2  Santiago de Cuba  Santiago de       Cuba
2   3         La Habana    La Habana           
3   4              Cuba                    Cuba
4   5      Havana, Cuba       Havana       Cuba
5   6   Santiago, Chile     Santiago      Chile
6   7             Chile                   Chile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you the answer your looking for IIUC

```
data = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'location':['Havana,Cuba', 'Santiago de Cuba' , 'La Habana', 'Cuba', 'Havana, Cuba', 'Santiago, Chile', 'Chile']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sample_list=['Cuba','Chile']
df[['location_1', 'location_2']] = df['location'].str.split('[,|.]', 1, expand=True)
for i in range(0, len(sample_list)):
    df['location_2'] = np.where(df['location'].str.contains(sample_list[i]), sample_list[i], df['location_2'])
df['location_2'] = df['location_2'].fillna(' ')
df
```

Comment: Using your code my location_2 is missing data from location_1 extract using sample_list. I added an example of what the final table should look like. Thx.

Comment: I updated my code to reflect the new specifications, the output should match your expected results.